# Conditions in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have two element in my XSD file:

```
<element name="accountnumber" type="" />
<element name="accounttype" type="" />
```

There are two types of account: 1) Saving 2) Current

The format of account number should be different for Saving and Current account type.

How can I achieve that in XSD? Is it possible to write ifs in XSD.

Comment: Just to confirm what you are asking, you are basically asking 2 questions, first how to define `accounttype` to be either "Savings" or "Checking" and to reject anything else.  And second, you are looking to define a format of the `accountnumber` based on the value in `accounttype`?

Comment: @psubsee2003 the first question can be done using restriction that I know...But I am asking the second question that you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

If `<SavingsAccount>` and `<CurrentAccount>` are different element names, then they can have different types, and both types can include an `<AccountNumber>` element, and these can have different types - just make sure that in each case AccountNumber is a local element declaration rather than a reference to a global element declaration.

That solution doesn't work if you are distunguishing the account type by means of an attribute, say `<account type="current">` and `<account type="savings">`. In this situation you will need to use the XSD 1.1 feature called Conditional Type Assignment, where the type of an element may depend on the values of its attributes. XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Xerces and Saxon.

Comment: It is possible to distinguish using an attribute, when the attribute is xsi:type.